# What voltage is a 3-LED light from a LED-TV?

Tags: led-strip

I have some "NDV rev1.1 4248 back lights" from a television.

There is a print that sais "94V" on the strip, and on the wire supplying the strips it said "96V".

Every strip has 9x buttons which have 3 LED's in them. So i devided 94 by 9 and figured that every button should have 10.4V roughly, which makes sense, because a white LED is normally 3.5 volts.

I have a 12v Lithium battery which measured 11.1V so i tested one of the LED's with it and it lasted less than one second.

Are the LED's are rated for 10.4V roughly and not more?

[image]

Comment: They probably are 3.3 volt leds, but at an unknown forward voltage. You connected a power supply without a resistor, killing them. These strips are undoubtedly designed to be controlled by a constant current driver.

Comment: Thanks. I need a specific LED driver then. I will see if i can get away with a 1amp 10.0v DC-DC converter for one, it's the only thing i have available. from the brightness it seems they are perhaps 0.5-1W.

Comment: Brightness is not a good indicator of wattage. The only thing that is is Forward Voltage and Current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you blew them out that quickly, it is most likely because LEDs need controlled *current*. Controlling only voltage to them doesn't work because they are diodes and have a "non-linear response" to voltage.

Try connecting a potentiometer to the + of your battery, turn the pot to about 1Kohm rssistance, then connect the 1 pod of leds & turn down the resistance until they light well without blowing.

Once you find a good point with the pot, measure voltage across your pot, then disconnect the battery & measure resistance the pot is set at. dividing the voltage (in volts) across the pot by the resistance setting (in ohms) will give you the current (in amps) that your leds need.

Answer (score 11):

The 94V marking you see on the PCB is *not* a supply voltage rating.
94V-0 is a UL marking indicating the flammability rating of the PCB material.
As others have said, you ideally need a constant-current LED driver or failing that a series resistor in order to drive that LED board safely.
If you know that they are white LEDs then expect each one to drop in the region of 3.3V.

Answer (score 0):

If you supplied it with 11.1V it will definitely fried your led's.
Your source supply is 94V, You have 3 strips with 9 led's for every strip w/c connected in series. The calculation for this is to multiply the number's of lead in every strip to the number of strips. It should be like this - Number of lead in every strips (9) X Number of strips (3) = 27 pcs. of leads.
Source supply is (94V) / total number of leads (27)  w/c is connected in series.
3.48V is the supply needed for the every leads to work perfectly.
I knew this because im a technician working with different kinds of LCD tv.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 black dots are the LED defuser mounting pads. There's only 1 LED per lens, so each strip in the picture has 9 LED's, at 3.3v = 29.7 V, (24v DC for a means of touch testing on the +/- spots on the connector end. If you "scratch" the white strip between each led, with 3v battery, (2 x AA soldered in series together) you can test each led. The one that doesn't light is the bad strip.